# Hessian matrix of level set function

Tags: differential-geometry, hessian-matrix

For a given level set function $\phi : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose zero level set presents a closed and smooth surface, what is a geometrical meaning of the following function?
\begin{align*}
f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{m}(\mathbf{x})^{\text{T}} \frac{Hess(\phi(\mathbf{x}))}{|\nabla \phi(\mathbf{x})|} \frac{\nabla \phi(\mathbf{x})}{|\nabla \phi(\mathbf{x})|},
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{m}(\mathbf{x}) \perp \nabla \phi(\mathbf{x})$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $Hess(\phi(\mathbf{x}))$ is a Hessian matrix of $\phi$ at $\mathbf{x}$. How should it be interpreted on zero level set in a differential geometry?

Comment: Could you provide some context or reference?

Comment: @rych : Sorry for a late reply. The context is actually from a tangential diffusion.